# Java Illegal Monitor State Exception

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to print odd and even numbers alternately using two different threads that coordinate among themselves using wait and notify and also using a lock.

```
public class OddEvenPrinter {
    private Object lock = new Object();
    private boolean printFlag = false;


     void printOdd() throws InterruptedException {
         for(int i=1; i < 25; i=i+2){
             synchronized (lock){
                 while(printFlag){
                     wait();
                 }
                 System.out.println(i + "********  PRINT ODD  ");
                 notifyAll();
             }
         }
    }

    void printEven() throws InterruptedException {
        for(int i=0; i < 25; i=i+2){
            synchronized (lock){
                while(!printFlag){
                    wait();
                }
                System.out.println(i + "********  PRINT EVEN  ");
                notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a Driver program to verify this. Can we not use synchronized block in a for loop. I am getting Illegal Monitor State exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        OddEvenPrinter printer = new OddEvenPrinter();
        Thread a = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    printer.printEven();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });

        Thread b = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    printer.printOdd();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });

        a.start();
        b.start();

        System.out.println("All DONE.....");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem:

You are synchronizing on `lock` object, but calling `wait()` which is equivalent to `this.wait()`.

Notice that **`this` represents different object than one held by `lock`**, and each of those objects has its own separate *monitor*.

Each of your threads at some point acquires monitor of `lock` but then via `this.wait()` it attempts to release monitor of `this`. Since it never acquired that monitor [`IllegalMonitorStateException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html) is thrown.

#### Solution:

Use `lock.wait()` and `lock.notifyAll()` since your threads are synchronizing on `lock`.

Comment: Thank you. People like you make stackoverflow a great place for developers. Yes, thats the mistake I made. I need to await and notify on the same object whose monitor I am using.

Comment: @Vineel You are welcome. Just small warning, this was only one of few problems in your code. You never modify `printFlag` so `while (!printFlag)` can be true for only one method. Also pay attention to its *initial* state.

Comment: sure, let me check, I have another question. If synchronized block alone can control access to printing odd/even, how would wait and notify make a difference in this case. Even though I wait(while in synchronized block), some one else have to be in synchronized block to able to notify me. But thats not possible right ?? Because I think only one thread can enter the synchronized block.

Comment: @Vineel "*Even though I wait(while in synchronized block), some one else have to be in synchronized block to able to notify me. But thats not possible right ??*" when thread invokes `lock.wait()` it *"returns"* monitor of `lock` and waits. Since now monitor is returned it allows some *other* thread to enter `synchronized(lock){..}` section and call `lock.notifyAll()`.